# Using polymer.dart to build portable web components

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer, polymer, web-component

I'd like to use polymer.dart to build a set of portable web components that can be embedded in any random html page (including pages outside of any dart project).  The idea is that a customer could embed my polymer.dart elements on his html pages without the customer needing to create a dart application.  I would think this would be an obvious and straightforward thing to do - but after going through many tutorials and instructional pages, and reading through lots of dart/polymer.dart documentation, I haven't found any explanation of how to go about this.  Presumably the dart/polymer code would have to be compiled to javascript for inclusion on the customer's html page.  Could someone comment on if this is possible, and if so, provide an explanation with examples of how to go about it?  This dart/polymer.dart newbie would be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work with Dart.
You need to run `pub build` over a Dart application to get a deployable result.
I guess this would work better with JavaScript Polymer elements.

There are plans to support this scenario but I guess it will still take a while.

Comment: I'm able to do exactly that kind of thing using GWT. Given that both GWT and Dart end up compiling to javascript, I'd think you should be able to accomplish this with Dart and Polymer.dart as well as with GWT.  I was hoping to replace GWT with Dart/Polymer.dart...

Comment: Maybe sometimes in the future.

Comment: You can't create web components in GWT yet, so how are you doing that, or what are you doing?

Comment: Probably just reusable widgets not web components according to the new web standard.

Comment: Günter is right. I created multiple GWT modules, and included them with individual <script> tags on an HTML page.  So these weren't "web components" a la W3C standard - but it allowed me to accomplish my goal of having standalone 'parts' that could be included/excluded as desired.  Understanding that I can't use Polymer.dart-based web components this way right now, is there a way to simulate with Dart what I did with GWT?  I suppose having each Dart component loaded into its own iFrame is one possibility, but I don't think that's a real solution.  I also need components to talk to each other.